# i am unable to Scroll and select element in Appium android ,in my Mobile app Automation Framework.?

Tags: android, mobile, ui-automation, appium-android, android-uiautomator

[This is my code snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PCTo.png).This code will select the element but won't scroll to exact element and select the value .Please help me to modify this ?

```
public void applyBedTimefromdate() throws  InterruptedException {
MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver
                .findElementsByAndroidUIAutomator(
                        "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.hdc:id/hour\")).getChildByText("
                                + "new UiSelector().className(\"android.view.View[@index='0']\"), \"3\"));");
        element.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try to scroll by Text with UiAutomator2.

add desired capability 'UiAutomator2' if you are using appium.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "UiAutomator2");
```

Now try below code.

```
public void scrollByText(String menuText) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textMatches(\"" + menuText + "\").instance(0));")); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Use below functions if you have element's id (Resource id)

```
 public void scrollByID(String Id, int index) {

        try {

             driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().resourceId(\""+Id+"\").instance("+index+"));")); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mussamil ,i applied your code to my program but it doesn't work .this page has few elements with scroll options .i want to first click on the item and then scroll to the desired value.Thanks

Comment: This function is only for scroll not click. you have to click first if required. Just pass the text  till you want to scroll i.e. 10 or 11 in your case after click. if scroll is not working then we can discuss further.

Comment: Yes ,I try this function for scroll .But i won't scroll my element.please check my image for understand the scenario.

Comment: Can you try this   driver.findElement(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator(
   "new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceIdMatches(\".*id/ID OF YOUR LOCATOR\")).flingForward()"));

Comment: Replace "ID OF YOUR LOCATOR" to "ID of locator"

Comment: Still not working .My component doesn't has text value for the selected item.My first code snap will scroll the element but won't get expected result.So is it possible to modify my code to scroll for some time interval then i can simulate my test scenario .Thanks

Comment: Expected result means? You want to scroll right? And “From” hours picker has text 10,11 12 etc. You can pass it in function mentioned in answer

Comment: Yes .but the values are not defined as text in selected element inspector.it has only class name,id and resource id.

Comment: Can you please upload element inspector image too? I will check then we can go scrolling with resource id too.

Comment: I have added Function for scrolling with resource id? Please give it a try

Comment: No.I have tried above solution.Still it not working .